# How to avoid uncaught reference error

Tags: javascript

I have a common function for many pages as below

```
function (){
 resetForm();
 $ajax call
 {
 // some code //
 }
}
```

now if i have not written the **resetForm()** fn in correspoding js, its giving the uncaught reference error as it should give and also my code followed after than line is not executed.

The js files where i have written **resetForm fn()** is working fine, but others are not.

The solution i have now is writing a blank resetForm function in other pages. Any other way ? 
thanks for the help

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish here. You want to call `resetForm()` only if it has been defined before, but ignore it otherwise?

Comment: It seems resetForm it's not defined by the time that code is executed. You need to reference the file containing that function before using it.

Comment: do you need that function be actually executed at that point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check with `typeof`

```
if (typeof resetForm === 'function') {
    resetForm()
}
// carry on.
```

This checks to see if you have a function called `resetForm` available and, if you do, executes it.

Comment: Upvoted because this not only checks if `resetForm` exists, but alos if it's a function.

Comment: @Cerbrus i think, the extra safety is specious since, although being some function, it may as well be the wrong one as it may be defined but as a string literal...

Comment: @fast: A "String literal"?

Comment: @fast - `typeof new String() === 'object'` and `typeof "a string" === 'string'`... What do you mean?

Comment: @RobH I mean that this explicit test for a function does not actually add safety: if you can't guarantee that there is not e.g. a 'var resetForm = "my reset form text";' you neither can guarantee that the function resetForm() is actually the right one... messy design.. - don't take this tooo literally/formally :-)

Answer (score 4):

you can check it it exists (globally) and only than call it by:

```
window.resetForm && resetForm();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few obvious options:

- Write a blank function like you did.
- `typeof resetForm === 'function' && resetForm();`
- Make sure to load only code that is relevant to the current page by better modularizing your code.

Answer (score 0):

just check if `resetForm` is defined:

```
if (resetForm) {
    resetForm();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not jquery-tagged question, but consider using jquery's onReady handler, it is executed when all javascript is loaded.

```
//main.js
$(function(){
    resetForm();
});

//functions.js
function resetForm() { .. }
```

It will call `resetForm` properly event if `resetForm` is in separate js and loaded after `main.js` is loaded.